# CSV import functionalityfor button not working for related fields

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Attaching my whole code for refrence-

Lightning component-

```
<aura:component controller="Persmissionset" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global">
 <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doit}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="Permissiontable" type="PermissionSetAssignment[]" />
    <div class="slds-m-around--xx-large">   
    <button class="slds-button slds-button--brand" onclick="{!c.downloadCsv}">Download As CSV</button> <br/><br/>
    <table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--cell-buffer">
  <thead>
    <tr class="slds-text-title--caps">

       <td scope="col">
                <b>User Name</b>
                </td>

       <th class="slds-is-sortable slds-text-title--caps" scope="col">
          <span class="slds-truncate" title="User Profile">User Profile</span>
       </th>

      <th scope="col">
        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Permission Set Name">PermissionSet Name</div>
      </th>

        <th scope="col">
        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Permission Set Name">UserRoleName</div>
      </th>

       <th scope="col">
        <div class="slds-truncate" title="Permission Set Name">Is User Active</div>
      </th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
        <tbody>
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.Permissiontable}" var="perm">

                  <tr>
      <th scope="row">
        <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!perm.Assignee.Name}">{!perm.Assignee.Name}</div>
      </th>

      <th scope="row">
        <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!perm.Assignee.Profile.Name}">{!perm.Assignee.Profile.Name}</div>
      </th>

       <th scope="row">
        <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!perm.PermissionSet.Label}">{!perm.PermissionSet.Label}</div>
      </th> 

        <th scope="row">
       <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!perm.PermissionSet.Label}">{!perm.Assignee.UserRole.Name}</div>
      </th> 

       <th scope="row">
        <div class="slds-truncate" title="{!perm.PermissionSet.Label}">{!perm.Assignee.IsActive}</div>
      </th>                

    </tr>

            </aura:iteration>

        </tbody>
    </table>    
         </div>
</aura:component>
```

apex class for fetching record-

```
public class Persmissionset {
@AuraEnabled 
     public static List<PermissionSetAssignment> permissonAssignment()
    { List<PermissionSetAssignment> PermissionList=new List<PermissionSetAssignment>
     ([SELECT PermissionSet.Name, PermissionSet.Id, PermissionSet.IsCustom, PermissionSet.Label, PermissionSet.PermissionsApiEnabled, Assignee.Name, Assignee.Id, Assignee.Profile.Name, Assignee.ProfileId, Assignee.UserRoleId, Assignee.UserRole.Name,Assignee.Profile.UserType, SystemModstamp, Assignee.isActive FROM PermissionSetAssignment 
       Where Assignee.isActive = True AND permissionSet.IsOwnedByProfile = FALSE 
       ORDER BY Assignee.Name ]);
     return PermissionList;

    }
}
```

Controller -

```
({
    doit : function(component, event, helper) { 

        var action = component.get("c.permissonAssignment");
        action.setCallback(this,function(response)
        {
            var state = response.getState();
           if(state == "SUCCESS"){
              // console.log("check");
               component.set("v.Permissiontable",response.getReturnValue());
                          }
            else{
               console.log("No Value for record"); 
            }
      }); 

            $A.enqueueAction(action);

    },
    downloadCsv : function(component,event,helper){

        // get the Records [contact] list from 'ListOfContact' attribute 
        var stockData = component.get("v.Permissiontable");


        // call the helper function which "return" the CSV data as a String   
        var csv = helper.convertArrayOfObjectsToCSV(component,stockData);   
         if (csv == null){return;} 

        // ####--code for create a temp. <a> html tag [link tag] for download the CSV file--####     
         var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');
          hiddenElement.href = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(csv);
          hiddenElement.target = '_self'; // 
          hiddenElement.download = 'ExportData.csv';  // CSV file Name* you can change it.[only name not .csv] 
          document.body.appendChild(hiddenElement); // Required for FireFox browser
          hiddenElement.click(); // using click() js function to download csv file
        //$A.enqueueAction(action);
        }
})
```

Helper ----

```
({
   onLoad: function(component, event) {
      //call apex class method
      var action = component.get('c.permissonAssignment');
      action.setCallback(this, function(response){
         //store state of response
         var state = response.getState();
         if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            //set response value in ListOfContact attribute on component.
            component.set('v.Permissiontable', response.getReturnValue());
         }
      });
      $A.enqueueAction(action);
   },

   convertArrayOfObjectsToCSV : function(component,objectRecords){
        // declare variables
        debugger;
        var csvStringResult, counter, keys, columnDivider, lineDivider;

        // check if "objectRecords" parameter is null, then return from function
        if (objectRecords == null || !objectRecords.length) {
            return null;
         }
        // store ,[comma] in columnDivider variabel for sparate CSV values and 
        // for start next line use '\n' [new line] in lineDivider varaible  
        columnDivider = ',';
        lineDivider =  '\n';

        // in the keys valirable store fields API Names as a key 
        // this labels use in CSV file header  
        keys = ['Assignee','AssigneeId','PermissionSet','Assignee'];
        // keym =['Assignee']

        csvStringResult = '';
        csvStringResult += keys.join(columnDivider);
        csvStringResult += lineDivider;

        for(var i=0; i < objectRecords.length; i++){   
            counter = 0;

             for(var sTempkey in keys) {
                var skey = keys[sTempkey] ; 

              // add , [comma] after every String value,. [except first]
                  if(counter > 0){ 
                      csvStringResult += columnDivider; 
                   }  
                 //if(counter == 0){ 
                     // csvStringResult += columnDivider; 
                     // alert("Here");
                     //console.log(':: Assignee  :: ' +objectRecords[i][skey].IsActive);
                  // }  

               if(typeof objectRecords[i][skey] === 'object')
               {
                   // console.log(':: Assignee Name :: ' +objectRecords[i][skey].Name)
                     csvStringResult += '"'+ objectRecords[i][skey].Name+'"';
                   //csvStringResult += '"'+ objectRecords[i][skey]+'"';
                 // csvStringResult += '"'+ objectRecords[i][skey].IsActive+'"';
                  //csvStringResult = '"'+ objectRecords[i][skey].IsActive+'"';
                   // csvStringResult += '"'+ objectRecords[i][skey].UserRole+objectRecords[i][skey].Name+'"';
                   //csvStringResult += '"'+ objectRecords[i][skey].Profile+'"'

                 }


          //   else
           //  {
             //  csvStringResult += '"'+ objectRecords[i][skey].IsActive+'"';   
            // }

               else
                 {
                    csvStringResult += '"'+ objectRecords[i][skey]+'"';            
                     }

               counter++;

            } // inner for loop close 
             csvStringResult += lineDivider;
          }// outer main for loop close 

       // return the CSV formate String 
        return csvStringResult;        
    }
})
```

I am stuck at this point unable to fetch value  `Assignee.Profile.Name` and other related fields in my code. Can anybody correct here?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@pushpesh try this out

keys = ['Assignee','AssigneeId','PermissionSet','Assignee'];

Now add an if else within below:
if(typeof objectRecords[i][skey] === 'object')

If index position = 0, then below
csvStringResult += '"'+ objectRecords[i][skey].Name+'"';

Else,(if index position = 3)
csvStringResult += '"'+ objectRecords[i][skey].isActive(or any other related field)+'"';

Let me know how it goes...

Comment: Hello Varun, thanks a lot really this saves lot of time for me.this works fine